# Restful API and SpringMVC, should I make path variables as @RequestBody object's fields for convenience?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I own an application for collecting feedback.

The api looks like this:

```
POST /customer/feedback/{feedbackId} HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9999
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Body: {'qaSays':'Approved', 'qaRating':98}
//This results the feedback (find by feedbackId) gets updated
```

The application is built using spring-mvc

```
//in controller
@RequestMapping(value="/customer/feedback/{feedbackId}")
@ResponseStatus(OK)
public void handle(@PathVariable("feedbackId") feedbackId, 
       @RequestBody ApproveFeedbackCommand command) {
     command.setFeedbackId(feedbackId);
     commandGateway.send(command);
}

//Command
public class ApproveFeedbackCommand {
     private String feedbackId;//makes no sense for client
     private String qaSays;
     private int qaRating;
}
```

The solution above works, but I have a feeling that something goes wrong here.

The question is:

**1.Should I use ApproveFeedbackCommand as @RequestBody just for convenience?** 
The extra field "feedbackId" may confuse the other developer, and it is annoying to set path variables manually.

**2.Should I add an ApproveFeedbackBody(exclude "feedbackId") for separate concerns?** 
But this seems to add some duplicate code and some manual command parameter extraction.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/customer/feedback/{feedbackId}")
@ResponseStatus(OK)
public void handle(@PathVariable("feedbackId") id, 
       @RequestBody ApproveFeedbackBody body) {
    ApproveFeedbackCommand command = convert(id, body);//manual convert here
    commandGateway.send(command);
}
```

Comment: Why isn't `feedbackId` sent as part of the JSON object?

Comment: @Bart Thank you, I forget to mention that this api aims to update the feedback resource. I thought it would be more appropriate to make feedbackId  a part of the resource url(Maybe I was wrong?).

Comment: The best part of handling JSON is that you can send pretty much anything inside the request body. In your examples I don't really see a need for the `feedbackId` to be in the URL.

Comment: @Bart I agree. but on the other hand, it is also recommended that url represents a individual resource. So POST/DELETE/PUT feedback/{feedbackId} should also makes sense. I was in a delima.

Comment: That is only true for `GET` requests but I wouldn't for modifying verbs. Simply because it's duplicate info. The client doesn't (or shouldn't) care and the server already has the ID from the request body.